# RxJava - repeat API call until result is complete

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have an API that returns `FamilyDetails`. I use retrofit to fetch them, and it is modelled as follows:

```
Observable<FamilyDetails> getFamilyDetails(@Query int personId);
```

Once fetched, those details will be used to update a `Person`. My API delivers those `FamilyDetails` as soon as it has some information to show, which means that the details may be incomplete, and thus there is a `complete = false` flag delivered in responses when the server hasn't finished fetching all family details - in turn, my app should send another request to fetch the remaining `FamilyDetails` if we receive `complete = false` in the first response, and keep doing so for as long as the details remain incomplete.

I have "somewhat" achieved what I wanted, but not entirely with this code:

```
personApiService.getFamilyDetails(personId)
    // repeat call
    .flatMap(familyDetails -> personApiService.getFamilyDetails(personId))
    // until family details are complete
    .takeUntil(familyDetails -> familyDetails.isComplete())
    // update the person object with the family details
    .flatMap(familyDetails -> Observable.just(updatePerson(familyDetails))
    //subscribe!
    .subscribe(personSubscriber);
```

My `personSubscriber` returns an updated `Person`.

The problem I have with this implementation is that partial updates don't go through `personSubscriber`'s `onNext()`, as I only get one call to `onNext()` with the updated `Person` object with its complete `FamilyDetails`.

I would like to model this using RxJava with the following requirements:

- if I receive incomplete details, I update the `Person`
  object those details belong to, and deliver it via `onNext()`.
- If we receive incomplete details, we keep querying the API for complete details, and deliver updated `Person` objects via `onNext()` in **the same observer**.
- Once we get the last `onNext()` call with the updated `Person`, then `onComplete()` is called and we are done.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
personApiService.getFamilyDetails(personId)
// repeat call
.repeat()
// until family details are complete
.takeUntil(familyDetails -> familyDetails.isComplete())
//subscribe (do your updates here)
.subscribe(personSubscriber);
```